# disable dispatchTouchEvent when I touch specific view in my activity

Tags: android, gesture

I use dispatchTouchEvent to make swipe gesture with the following code

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean result = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        // disable the gesture in this screen because we have   
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

and I want to use SignatureView to capture customer signature using 
https://github.com/CoatedMoose/CustomViews/blob/master/library/src/com/coatedmoose/customviews/SignatureView.java
so I want to disable the swipe gesture when the user click in the SignatureView , How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the `SignatureView` project, but for a regular `GesturDetector` you can so something like the following to pass events to the `GestureDetector` only when it's in the range of its "target" `View`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    boolean result = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    if (inSignatureArea(ev)) {
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }     
}

public boolean inSignatureArea(MotionEvent ev) {
    float eventX = ev.getX();
    float eventY = ev.getY();
    return (eventX > signatureArea.getX() && eventX < (signatureArea.getX() + signatureArea.getWidth())) ;
    // && (same thing for Y and height); 
}
```

You should be able to adapt it to your needs.